# Compute the degree of a map on the sphere with a property of symmetry

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology

Suppose a continuous map $f : S^2 \rightarrow S^2$ verifies this property :
$$ \forall x \in S^2, f(x) - f(-x) = 2\left(f(x),x\right)x $$
An equivalent expression could be :
$$f(x) = X(x) + u(x)x$$
where $X$ is a tangent vector field on the sphere, $u$ a function with :
$$ X(-x)=X(x) \hspace{15mm} u(-x)=u(x) \hspace{15mm} \left|X\right|^2 + u^2 = 1$$
For instance, the identity and antipodal maps are solutions of degree $1$ and $-1$.
The question is : can we find solutions $f$ of other degree ? I particularly want to know if there exist solutions of degree $0$.

Comment: Is $(f(x),x)$ the dot/scalar product of $f(x)$ and $x$, as vectors in $\mathbb R^3$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. We can also see this symmetry such as :
$$ f(-x) = S_x . f(x) $$
Where $S_x$ denotes the orthogonal symmetry with respect to the orthogonal plan to $x$ :
$$S_x(y) = y - 2(y,x)x$$